# Writing a GUI to display statistics

Tags: c++, user-interface, statistics, numbers, visualization

I'm working with a hardware simulator for a project. It outputs statistics at the end in a very structured but ugly way. It can be tiresome to read so I would like to write a GUI to help me display it better. Would anybody have an idea of what framework and widgets I could use to quickly and painlessly construct something clean? I would like to be able to navigate the subnodes of the tree and hide (collapse) nodes I'm not interested in.

The statistics output take a form like this

---

```
root {
 foo = "bar";
 foo_num = 1;
 machine {
  core0 {
   fetch {
    renamed {
      none = 13559;
      flags = 3013;
      reg_and_flags = 10735;
      reg = 8430;
    }
     width[5] = {
      Minimum:                   381
      Maximum:                 17450
      Average:                 1.248
      Total Sum:               28627
      Weighted Sum:            35737
      Threshold:                   3
      [ 61.0% ] [ 61.0% ]     0     0 17450 ******************************
      [  1.3% ] [ 62.3% ]     1     1   381 
      [ 12.1% ] [ 74.4% ]     2     2  3476 ******
      [  3.1% ] [ 77.5% ]     3     3   876 *
      [ 22.5% ] [  100% ]     4     4  6444 ***********
    };
     status (total 57920) {
      [  0.0% ] rob_full = 0; { (zero) }
      [ 35.9% ] ldq_full = 20789;
      [  2.4% ] fetchq_empty = 1394;
      [  0.0% ] physregs_full = 0; { (zero) }
      [ 61.7% ] complete = 35737;
      [  0.0% ] stq_full = 0; { (zero) }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

---

There is already a parser that creates a kind of tree from a binary file, it is written in C++ so perhaps it is better if a choose a framework for this language. An alternative would be to generate XML output and then use another language to process the information.

I'm not very experienced with visual programming and I don't really know what kind of widgets are available. Any suggestions and pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your dev toolchain - windows using Visual Studio, or something else?

Comment: Check with your users.  I proposed making really cool charts out of statistical data once but the users didn't want them and preferred rows and columns of numbers (accountants).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I'm just trying to display some information, and I don't really need interaction, I sometimes make the program output a simple html page.  It's fast and trivial to do things like tables and images (in virtually any format).  If you need graphs, there are web-APIs like Google's [chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

Comment: That's a very good idea, I feel a bit silly that it didn't occur to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend **boost::spirit::qi** for parsing, and **Qt** + **QWT** - for graphics. They are all C++. **QWT** (which is based on **Qt**) has multiple convenient graph widgets out of the box.

spirit: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html
Qt: http://qt.nokia.com/products
QWT: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

**EDIT**

More specifically:
Tree view: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreeview.html
Histograms: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_histogram.html

It's all pretty simple to use, check out the samples to find out exactly how is it done.

Comment: Thanks, is there a particular widget you would suggest is suitable? I think this is the ultimate question. I don't really need to do anything fancy with the numbers, I just need to present them in a clean and easy to read format. I think a simple GUI would be more suitable than doing strange things with the text output. :-)

Comment: Agreed.  If Qt is too heavyweight, you can also check out wxWidgets: http://www.wxwidgets.org/ - wxTreeCtrl would be the specific widget.

Comment: Looks useful and simple, great suggestion. Thank you